# Find lldp informations using snmpwalk or another method

Tags: java, networking, snmp, topology

I want to build a java tool that extracts lldp informations of some devices (switches, routers, etc) to make a 'topology map'.

Trying snmpwalk, i found only useless informations (for this case).
I think lldp mib is 1.0.8802.1.1.2, but i'm not sure.

Anyone knows how to extract this, using snmpwalk or another method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [IEEE 802](http://www.ieee802.org/1/files/public/MIBs/LLDP-MIB-200505060000Z.txt) MIB document, what append when you try to walk on this OID :

```
1.0.8802.1.1.2.1
```

I stands for :

```
iso std(0) iso8802(8802) ieee802dot1(1) ieee802dot1mibs(1) lldpMIB(2) lldpObjects(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via SNMPWALK. IF-MIB/IP-MIB are the generic MIBs that will provide you with good enough data to build something like that. If its just for Cisco than CDP-MIB will give you everything that you would need. Let me know if you are trying to make something vendor neutral.